# Disparar evento (F11)?

Tags: javascript

Preciso disparar o evento (F11) do teclado por meio do javascript ? Afim de acionar o fullscreen (tela cheia) assim que uma determinada app web for pre-carregada.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer isso nos navegadores modernos, que não seja dentro de um evento de teclado ou mouse.

Neste caso pode usar este código para colocar em tela cheia:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Full screen.</button>
<div id="full" style="background-color: green;">Tela cheia</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  function requestFullScreen(element) {
    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullscreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
      requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
      var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      if (wscript !== null) {
        wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
      }
    }
  }

  var elem = $("#full")[0]; // Make the body go full screen.
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    requestFullScreen(elem);
  });
});
</script>
```

[Resposta original no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7525760/195417)

Comment: ótimo exemplo Miguel +1